# add page title to latest posts frontpage in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I set my reading section to latest posts in Wordpress. My homepage logs fine but I would like to add a page title above the posts.  I have looked in my theme's files and couldn't find the file to edit.  As a test, I tried to add an image to my theme's loop.php and it appeared above the post on my homepage.  The location was right but the image appeared on every one of my category blog list pages.  How do I add a page title to the homepage that only appears on the homepage above the blog list?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources for you to use, WordPress: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Eg:
you can use

```
<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?>
```

There is lot of resources on WordPress, best of luck!